# How to test for ObjectID vs just hex string in python

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a generic method for querying one mongodb collection (A) about ids from a separate mongodb collection (B).  Here's what I have so far:

```
def getOtherCollInfo(self, otherCollObj, queryField, outputField="_id"):

    selfIdList = self.getIds() # gets a set of ids from whole collection (B)
    returned_dict = {}
    for selfId in selfIdList:
        curs_obj = otherCollObj.find({queryField : str(selfId)}).distinct(outputField) #otherCollObj is the 'collection (A)
        temp_list=[]
        for obj in curs_obj:
            temp_list.append(obj)
            returned_dict[selfId]=temp_list
    return returned_dict
```

This works fine for collection A where the `query_field` looks like:

```
542de00c763f4a7f558be12f
```

When attempting this method on a third collection (C), it fails (I think) because the `query_field` is just the hex sting:

```
ObjectId('542de00c763f4a7f558be12f')
```

Is there a way to test the formatting of the id so I can make the method more generic?

Comment: just to clarify, do you want to check whether the string is a valid mongoID?

Comment: They are all valid mongo ids.  I'm trying to write a method that will work for both formats.

Comment: By query_field do you mean the key or the value? keys can only be strings in MongoDB.I assume you mean selfId is 542de00c763f4a7f558be12f or ObjectId('542de00c763f4a7f558be12f')?